# Trouble passing in variable names for R user defined functions

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to create a function to recode variables into a new variable, based on the coding provided in one variable, and the skip pattern in another.

I've created a trivial example:

```
data <- data.frame(A=1:4, B=c(1,1,1,2))
```

My function is as follows:

```
recode_4scale <- function (var, name, skip, df){
  df$name <- df$var #generate new variable
  df[which(df$skip==2),"name"] <- 5 #replace with 5 if skip pattern
  df[is.na(df$var),"name"] <- 6 #replace with 6 if missing
  df$name <- df$name == 3 | df$name==4 #code as true if 3 or 4
  df$name <- as.factor(df$name)
  return (df)
}
data1<-recode_4scale(A, new, B, data)
```

I get: Warning message:
In is.na(df$var) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

What I expect to get by running it line by line:

```
data$new <- data$A
data[which(data$B==2),"new"] <- 5
data[is.na(data$A),"new"] <- 6
data$new <- data$new == 3 | data$new == 4
data$new <- as.factor(data$new)
data$new
[1] FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE
Levels: FALSE TRUE
```

I believe I'm having trouble passing the names in, given that I can't get anything out of even the most simple function.

Any idea what's going wrong here? (I also know that this is not the best way to write this thing in general, new employee fixing old code, will improve it once I get it running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object$variable` does not do a substitution on `variable`.
Rather it assumes there is something already called `variable` (not the value of `variable`, but the actual string "variable") in your object.
However, the following will work:

```
data <- data.frame(A=1:4, B=c(1,1,1,2))
variable <- "A"
data[[variable]]  # Same as df[["A"]] or df$A
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

So, your function should be:

```
recode_4scale <- function (var, name, skip, df){
  df[[name]] <- df[[var]] #generate new variable
  df[which(df[[skip]]==2), name] <- 5 #replace with 5 if skip pattern
  df[is.na(df[[var]]), name] <- 6 #replace with 6 if missing
  df[[name]] <- df[[name]] == 3 | df[[name]] == 4 #code as true if 3 or 4
  df[[name]] <- as.factor(df[[name]])
  return (df)
}
data1 <- recode_4scale("A", "new", "B", data)
data1
#   A B   new
# 1 1 1 FALSE
# 2 2 1 FALSE
# 3 3 1  TRUE
# 4 4 2 FALSE
```

Comment: thanks so much! this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Great! If this answers your question, please upvote the answer and mark it as the answer (click the gray "check" mark).

Comment: Wait @Alexey Shiklomanov, one issue--I'm not getting the right value for row 4: it should be "FALSE" (because B=2).  I think it's generating a new "name" variable instead of replacing data$new with 5, which is what happens when I run it manually.

Comment: If that's what you're trying to do, that line of the function should probably be: `df[[name]] <- df[[skip]] == 3 | df[[skip]] == 4`, because you are comparing against the value of the `skip` column...?

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is add things that are missing (or should be but aren't) because of the skip pattern into the "false" column.  I don't think that line gets me there unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Here's the step by step tracking if I do it manually:
> data$new <- data$A

> table (data$new)


1 2 3 4 

1 1 1 1 

> data[which(data$B==2),"new"] <- 5

> table (data$new)


1 2 3 5 

1 1 1 1 
> data[is.na(data$A),"new"] <- 6

> table (data$new)


1 2 3 5 

1 1 1 1 

> data$new <- data$new == 3 | data$new == 4

> table (data$new)


FALSE  TRUE 

    3     1 

> data$new <- as.factor(data$new)

> table (data$new)


FALSE  TRUE 

    3     1

Comment: I see. I think my revisions did what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes! that fixes it.